# Вывод данных из базы данных с правильной группировкой

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, календарь

Добрый день Всем, прошу помощи..
Не могу правильно вывести в таблицу данные.

Имеется три таблицы в бд:

1. `city(id, name)`
2. `week_days(id, name)`
3. `report(id, city_id, week_day_id, value)`

Содержимое таблицы  report :

```
1 | 1 | 1 | 10

2 | 1 | 2 | 08

3 | 1 | 3 | 05

4 | 1 | 1 | 02
```

Имеется код который вытаскивает эти данные:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test','root','');
$getDays = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM week_days");//Достаем дни недели
$getDays->execute();
$resultDays = array();
$resultDays = $getDays->fetchAll();//Создаем массив дней
$getCity = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM city");//Достаем города
$getCity->execute();
$resultCity = array();
$resultCity = $getCity->fetchAll();//Создаем массив городов
        $getTables= $db->prepare("SELECT r.*, c.name as city_name 
        FROM report as r INNER JOIN city as c ON(r.city_id = c.id) 
        INNER JOIN week_days as wd ON(r.week_day_id = wd.id) 
       ");
        $getTables->execute();
        $result =  $getTables->fetchAll();
        $resultTables =$result;
        $result1=$result;
        for($i=0;$i<count($resultTables);$i++){
            $ress[$i]=$resultTables[$i];
            foreach($resultDays as $day){
                $ress[$i]["days"][$day['id']]="";
                if($day['id'] == $resultTables[$i]['day']){
               $ress[$i]["days"][$day['id']]=$resultTables[$i]['value'];
                }else{

                        foreach($result1 as $kr=>$table1){
                            if($day['id']==$table1['week_day_id'] && $table1['city_id']==$resultTables[$i]['city_id'] && $resultTables[$i]['id'] != $table1['id'] ){
                                $ress[$i]["days"][$day['id']]=$table1['value'];
                            }
                        }

                }

            }
        }
<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9">
    <h1>Таблица</h1>
      </div>
      <div class='col-lg-3'>
        <div class="thumbnail">
             <div class="caption">
               <h3>Добавить В Календарь</h3>
               <p><select class='filial form-control'>
               <option value='0'>--Филиал--</option>
               <?php if(!empty($resultCity )){//если массив не пустой?>
                  <?php foreach($resultCity  as $city){?>
                     <option value="<?=$city['id']?>"><?=$city['name']?></option>
                  <?php }?>
               <?php }?>
               </select></p>
               <p><select class='day form-control'>
               <?php if(!empty($resultDays)){//если массив не пустой?>
                  <?php foreach($resultDays  as $day){?>
                     <option value="<?=$day['id']?>"><?=$day['name']?></option>
                  <?php }?>
               <?php }?>
               </select></p>
               <p><input type='text' class='time_fil form-control' placeholder='Время'></p>
               <p><button class="save_this btn btn-primary" role="button">Добавить</button> </p>
             </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h2>Календарь</h2>
      <table class='table table-striped'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Филиал</th>
            <?php if(!empty($resultDays)){//если массив не пустой?>
                  <?php foreach($resultDays  as $day){?>
                     <th><?=$day['name']?></th>
                  <?php }?>
               <?php }?>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php  if(!empty($ress)){?>
            <?php foreach($ress as $table){?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$table['id'].")".$table['city_name']?></td>
                    <?php if(!empty($table['days'])){ foreach($table['days'] as $day){?>
                        <td><?=$day?></td>
                    <?php } ?>
               </tr>
                <?php }}?>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
```

При данном запросе выйдет таблица:

```
ГОРОД | Понедельник | Вторник | Среда |  Четверг | Пятница | Суббота | Воскресенье

Москва  | 10 | | | | | | |

Москва |  | 08 | | | | | |

Москва | | | 05 | | | | |

Москва | 02 | | | | | | |
```

И это не правильно, нужно чтобы вывелось так:

```
ГОРОД | Понедельник | Вторник | Среда |  Четверг | Пятница | Суббота | Воскресенье

Москва  | 10 | 08 | 05 | | | | |

Москва  | 02 | | | | | | |
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, уже бьюсь не один день...

Comment: сформулируйте правила, по которым должна строиться таблица. глядя со стороны, строите вы pivot, но ожидаете какой-то совсем странный результат получить.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, 
PIVOT крутая штука - но она больше подходит для суммирования значений, а мне нужно чтобы значения были уникальны например если имеется два значения в понедельнике то в табличке это вывелось как две строки....Это не знаю как сделать

Comment: Сейчас я сделал sql запрос такой: 

SELECT city_id,

MAX(IF(day_id='1',value, NULL)) as day1,

MAX(IF(day_id='2',value, NULL)) as day2,

MAX(IF(day_id='3',value, NULL)) as day3,

MAX(IF(day_id='4',value, NULL)) as day4,

MAX(IF(day_id='5',value, NULL)) as day5,

MAX(IF(day_id='6',value, NULL)) as day6,

MAX(IF(day_id='7',value, NULL)) as day7

FROM  report

GROUP BY city_id

получил результат: 

Москва (1) ,  12, 08, 05, null,null,null,null

а нужно: 


Москва (1) ,  10, 08, 05, null,null,null,null

Москва (1) ,  02,  null, null, null,null,null,null

Answer (score 1):

Не ясно чем отличаются строки

```
1 | 1 | 1 | 10
```

и

```
4 | 1 | 1 | 02
```

Кроме позиции в таблице, которая не гарантируется базой данных: что-то удалите и запись из другой последовательности может оказаться выше. Т.е. 10 и 02 могут поменяться местами. Обе записи относятся к Москве и к понедельнику, как понять что первая запись должна быть в первой последовательности, а вторая - во второй? Нужны дополнительные поля, которые позволят выполнить группировку. В текущем варианте решить задачу однозначно не представляется возможным.